# If statement problem in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to show rows of data in a table with the following code. In case there is no data for the table I want a simple message to be printed. My code does print the rows of data as intended when there is data to show but when the list is empty it prints the table headings. How can I get rid of the headings and print the message instead?

```
<fieldset>

    <legend>Department Membership</legend>
<% if(Model.departmentsDisplayCheck) {%>
<table>
    <tr>         
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var dep in Model.departmentsList){ %>

    <tr>
        <td><%: Html.ActionLink(dep.Name, "Details", "Department", new { id=dep.DepartmentID}, null) %></td>
        <td><%: dep.Type %></td>
        <td><%: dep.Age %></td>
        <td><%: dep.Gender.ToString() %></td>
        <td><%: dep.Status %></td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
<% } %>
<% else { %>
<p><%: "You are not currently a member of any Department." %></p>
<% } %>
</table>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off these kinds of checks don't belong in a View.  Instead you should have a property on your controller called something like DisplayDepartmentList and then set it using your checks (and any other business logic that may come up) there.

Then instead you are doing this check..

```
<% if(Model.DisplayDepartmentList)
```

Comment: +1, that's the best and most correct answer. Use view models instead of spaghetifying your views (the process of writing spaghetti code in your views).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is my first ever project and any info on improving my code is greatly appreciated. I did what you suggested but I still can't make the message appear in the place of the table. Should I use a different view model for each case?

Comment: @Darin - How is that any different than my answer?  You still need to do the check.  You will have the same amount of code, just a smaller if statement (but more Controller code) ...

Comment: @Martin, in your answer you are doing the check in the view. You are writing multiple ugly conditions in it. That's really a code to be written in a view. It's a code that belongs to the view model which is exactly what ShaneC proposed in his answer by introducing a new boolean property called `DisplayDepartmentList`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<% if(Model.departmentsList != null && Model.departmentsList.Count > 0) {%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The headings are gone now but the message is still not being printed. I used this though as I was getting an error: <% if(Model.departmentsList != null && Model.departmentsList.Count() > 0) {%>

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the model is null and not just empty? If it's coming back empty then you'd get the observed behavior.

Try changing it to

```
<% if(Model.departmentsList != null || Model.departmentList.Count == 0) {%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no difference with the OR statement. Headings still show.